# JavaScript : Shortcircuit choose between JSON Stringify & String() depends upon output

Tags: javascript, json

My code sometimes returns an object as output and sometimes string.
Is there any way I can write one line code or JS short circuit so that my code will automatically pick JSON.stringify() or String() regards to the type of the output.

For example :

```js
console.log(typeof getResponseFromAPI("xxx","e0f9619c8-asjjdd889") == "object" && JSON.stringify(getResponseFromAPI("xxx","e0f9619c8-asjjdd889") || String(getResponseFromAPI("xxx","e0f9619c8-asjjdd889")));
```

Its looks big, is there any I can reduce?

Comment: Are you able to change what is returned from the API?

Comment: No, and no you *should not* even try to put this in one line.

Comment: @chazsolo, the response from the API, yes I can extract information from it. Changing at source?, its huge codebase, so I want to go around it.

Comment: Why not fix the source of `getResponseFromAPI` to have a consistent return type? Please post its code so that we can assist with that.

Comment: If you can't change what is returned from the API, then you can atleast cache the response first instead of calling it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a local variable so that you don't call `getResponseFromAPI` multiple times, and also you should use the conditional operator instead of short-circuiting `&&` and `||`:

```
const res = getResponseFromAPI("xxx","e0f9619c8-asjjdd889"); console.log(typeof res == "object" ? JSON.stringify(res) : String(res));
```

I would also suggest to write these statements in two or even four lines.

Answer (score 1):

Stringify does return a string if you pass a string in parameter. So in your case you can simply use stringify any way.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify("toto")); // '"toto"'
console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5 })); // '{"x":5}'
```